# Edit Rails migration file in one command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell

This is a shell scripting question really, but relates to rails.

I create a Rails migration like this:

```
~/dropbox/rails/f6$ rails g migration ModifyWord
```

Rails then creates the migration script, and reports the name back on the console:

```
~/dropbox/rails/f6$ rails g migration ModifyWord
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20121231080052_modify_word.rb
```

I then edit the migration file using vi, like this:

```
~/dropbox/rails/f6$ vi db/migrate/20121231080052_modify_word.rb
```

I'd like to be able to do the vi *filename* as a single command, perhaps via a shell script that can have an alias to it added to my .bash_rc.

That is, I would run the command after the migration and it would look at the filename reported.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

***SOLUTION***

Based on per Michaël Witrant's suggestion, I have added to aliases to my bash profile.

- **cm** to cat the last created migration file
- **vm** to vi the last created migration file

  alias cm='cat `ls db/migrate/*.rb | tail -n 1`'

  alias vm='vi `ls db/migrate/*.rb | tail -n 1`'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it starts with a time stamp, it should always be the last file alphabetically so I'd simply do something like this:

```
vi `ls db/migrate/*.rb | tail -n 1`
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks I'll try it out and create as an alias. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with this:

```
rails generate migration AddDetailsToProducts part_number:string price:decimal
```

will generate this in the migration file:

```
class AddDetailsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
    add_column :products, :price, :decimal
  end
end
```

So, you do not have to separately edit the migration file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am familiar with the full syntax: I was adding, removing and renaming all on the same table.